# Pass parameters to a vega-lite spec?

Tags: vega-lite

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to pass parameters into a vega-lite spec via vegaEmbed(). For example, I'd like to pass the data url, so that instead of my spec containing:

```
"data": {"url": "filename.json"},
```

it contained something like:

```
"data": {"url": parameters["dataURL"]},
```

At a high level, I want to display visualizations from external applications via a url, something like `http://localhost/showViz.html?data=today.json&sort=ascending` so it's not just about specifying the data source, I'm looking for a general mechanism to parameterize my specs.

I tried passing something via vegaEmbed's *opt* argument, but couldn't work-out how to access it from the vega-lite spec (either as *usermeta* or not). If the *opt* argument is the preferred way to do something like this, then my question devolves to "how do I reference *opt* and/or *usermeta* values from a vega-lite spec?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no standard means to parametrize inputs that is built-in to Vega or Vega-Lite.

There are third-party tools that do something similar to what you have in mind, for example [Vega Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/blog/custom-vega-visualizations-in-kibana), which provides a templating syntax for charts.

If you want to do this using native Vega/Vega-Lite, you can always use Javascript to modify the specification before passing it to the renderer, and/or use the vega-embed `patch` option to provide a javascript function that will patch the **Vega** specification (not Vega-Lite specification) before it is rendered.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm already hacking the spec with Javascript, but it's a bit cumbersome (and feels a bit dirty), so thought there might be a cleaner/more-idiomatic way.